# Visual Studio 2015.2 with Xamarin for Mobile app automation (UI) testing

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I got a new project to work on mobile automation testing. I have no experience with mobile and I have just started to look into Xamarin plug in with Visual Studio 2015.

It looks pretty good plug in / extension to work with Visual Studio. I have seen below video on how to use Xamarin Test Recorder with Visual Studio.
https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Visual-Studio/Visual-Studio-2017-Launch/APP-103
https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/XamarinShow/User-Interface-Automation-with-Charles-Wang

Videos are pretty clear on how to do automation testing and I could do the same. However the blockage I have is no where I am able to see how the great UI interface (emulator / simulator) came into picture. Where to get it ? which one to use ?

To reach the point of the recording or writing my code for UI Automation, I need to understand all the pre requisites and how to get the emulator and other stuffs.

Could some one please share details on above points.

Thanks in advance.

Best Regards,
Ahetejazahmad Khan.

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/